# Django Forms error when calling requesting POST method

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So I am using Django version 1.6.5 and I am trying to create a simple form .
and I have this view

```
   def create(request):
       if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
           form = WatchForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
           if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
               return HttpResponseRedirect('Watch/index.html') # Redirect after POST
           else: 
            return render(request, 'Watch/create.html', {'form': form,})
        else:
            form = WatchForm() # An unbound form

       return render(request, 'Watch/create.html', {
       'form': form,
        })
```

and this is my form

```
    from django import forms
    from Watch.models import Watch

    class WatchForm(forms.Form):
        idNumber=forms.CharField(max_length=30)
        brand = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
        #relisedDate =forms.DateTimeField('date published')
        referenceNumber = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
        sortDescription=forms.CharField(max_length=200)
        fullDescription=forms.CharField(max_length=600)
```

I have also created a template called create.html

```
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

and this is my urlpatterns entry 
        url(r'^create$',views.create),

So when I  use this URL /watch/create/ the form does appear in my browser  but when I submit I receive this error :

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/watch/create/

   Using the URLconf defined in miWatch.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this          order:
   ^watch/ ^$ [name='index']
   ^watch/ ^create$
   ^watch/ ^(?P<watch_id>[0-9]+)/$ [name='detail']
   ^watch/ ^(?P<watch_id>[0-9]+)/results/$ [name='results']
   ^watch/ ^(?P<watch_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$ [name='vote']
   The current URL, watch/create/, didn't match any of these.
```

and this is the output of the monitor

```
     [23/Jun/2014 07:53:52] "GET /watch/create HTTP/1.1" 200 1084
     [23/Jun/2014 07:54:01] "POST /watch/create/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2766
     [23/Jun/2014 07:54:08] "GET /watch/create/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2765
```

Anybody can give me  clarification on why is this happening and what is it that I am missing  ??
Thanks in advance !

Comment: The error page (when DEBUG=True) should show the list of URLs that were tried. Can you show us that please?

Comment: On a somewhat related note, please look into using reverse: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

Answer (score 2):

Change `action` attribute in your form as

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

This will submit the form to current url.

Comment: I did but still getting the same exactly the same error !

Comment: Like that ? isn't the second else statement handling the GET method ?

Comment: @Nikolis.Py, Have you updated the template? show us updated code

Comment: @Nikolis.Py, change your url pattern to has `/` , like `url(r'^create/$',views.create),`

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a trailing slash:

```
Using the URLconf defined in miWatch.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this          order:
   ^watch/ ^$ [name='index']
   ^watch/ ^create$ #  <-- No Trailing Slash! 

   The current URL, watch/create/, didn't match any of these.
```

Change your URL by appending a slash:

```
url(r'^create/$',views.create),
```

The reason that you are seeing the form display when you're GETting the URL is because you're not adding the slash, and you're loading the page manually. Django likes to have trailing slashes - don't fight that. Not sure why posting to an empty action is appending the slash, but that sounds like a HTML thing rather than a Django issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is your url setting defined on root level ? If so you need to fix the path to

```
url(r'^watch/create$',views.create)
```

Comment: no it's not it is  the one inside the app's directory.

Answer (score 0):

Add a slash to your url

```
url(r'^watch/create/$', views.create)
```

Return your form re-rendered when its not valid, with data and error messages.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def create(request):
    # POST
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = WatchForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
        # ...
        return HttpResponseRedirect('Watch/index.html') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        # Not valid, re-render form with data and error messages
        return render(request, 'Watch/create.html', {'form': form,})

    return render(request, 'Watch/create.html', {
      'form': form,
    })
```

Correct the action in your form template:

```
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it does not seem to solve my issue .
When it comes to the url conf file this is the url conf file that is in the specific app not the one that is in the mySite directory ,so I can't add watch/create cause it would look like that watch/watch/create .